# Website with FB likes not showing in user newsfeed

Tags: facebook-like, timeline, feed

I have a website with FB like integration/personalization but when I 'share to facebook' the story does not show up in my newsfeed, only my Timeline! I really would like this to show up in the newsfeed as well. What do I need to do/check/change?
website is [Once in Verona](http://www.onceinverona.com)

Comment: is it suppose to be showing in news-feed!?
I do not think you can do something, because newsfeeds are from facebook side. not the programer side!

Comment: I've seen other websites post to the newsfeed... How do spotify and other apps like that do it?

Comment: those are applications in facebook. not shares!
https://www.facebook.com/appcenter

Comment: What about via the open graph?